# Multiple Rooms Within Dynamic Namespaces in Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io, webrtc

I'm using Socket.IO to deploy a real-time drawing canvas application with Node.JS and Express but here's the problem I'm facing:

Even though I created namespaces to connect peers to namespaces according to pathnames they're visiting 
(normally — /webrtc/:id), the application does a poor job of isolating two different pathnames. So it also connects two different pathnames but oddly, with a one-sided connection.

For example, if I were to go to **localhost:3000/webrtc/1** on one tab and **/webrtc/2** on the other, the first tab peer would transmit drawing data to the other one while the second one wouldn't.

P.S it does well within the same pathnames.

P.P.S I mean **document.href.pathname** by saying pathname.

Here's the source:

**SERVER**

```
 var io = require('socket.io')(server);


 app.get('/webrtc/:id', function(req, res, next) {
     className = '/webrtc/' + req.params.id;
     nsp = io.of(className);
     res.render('webrtc');

     nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
           socket.on('drawing', (data) => nsp.emit('drawing', data));
           });
 })
```

**CLIENT**

```
  var socket = io(document.location.pathname);
```

Comment: You're adding a `connection` event to a namespace every time a client connects. After a second client has connected to one namespace, every `drawing` event will be broadcasted twice by everyone in the room.

Comment: Thank you. How do I fix this?